# streaming video on website

Tags: video, web, streaming, rtsp, ip-camera

I have an IP camera which produces a RTSP stream and I'd like to ask you what would be the best way to put it to a website. The first thing I was thinking about was putting it directly as an [object](http://live.v2.nl/embed.php), but I'm afraid that multiple users viewing it could cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer supports it.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/

Something like this:

```
<script src="jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="livecam"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer('livecam').setup({
'flashplayer': 'player.swf',
'file': 'camera.stream',
'streamer': 'rtmp://00.00.00.00:1234/streaming',
'autostart': 'true',
'controlbar': 'bottom',
'stretching': 'exactfit',
'width': '640',
'height': '352'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there some performance difference between e.g. realplayer and this javascript player? I think that there still might be a problem with multiple users.